# Orika Mapping using BoundedMapperFacade for classes containing other objects

Tags: java, orika

I have classes of the form -

```
class EdgeMtuMismatchEvent {
    private final List<MtuInterfaceMap> list = new ArrayList<>();
    private int id;

    // public getters and setters
}
```

I have to map the above class to something like below

```
class EdgeMtuMismatchEventUI {
    private final List<MtuInterfaceMapUI> list = new ArrayList<>();
    private int id;

    // public getters and setters
}
```

I know I can have the mapper like below

```
    final DefaultMapperFactory factory = new DefaultMapperFactory.Builder().build();
    factory.classMap(MtuInterfaceMap.class, MtuInterfaceMapUI.class).byDefault().register();
    factory.classMap(EdgeMtuMismatchEvent.class, EdgeMtuMismatchEventUI.class).byDefault().register();
//factory.getMapperFacade().map()
```

As [Orika performance tuning](https://orika-mapper.github.io/orika-docs/performance-tuning.html) guide says

> Use BoundMapperFacade to avoid repeated lookup of mapping strategy

So I am looking for something using the `BoundedMapperFacade` like below for better performance

```
BoundMapperFacade<EdgeMtuMismatchEvent, EdgeMtuMismatchEventUI> facade = factory.getMapperFacade(EdgeMtuMismatchEvent.class, EdgeMtuMismatchEventUI.class, false)
```

I am not able to figure out how can I add the mapper for `MtuInterfaceMap` in the above code snippet.

Can anyone suggest anything?

Comment: `BoundMapperFacade` will lazily obtain the resolved mapping strategy from the mapper factory and cache it, so if the `MtuInterfaceMap` mapper is registered with the `MapperFactory`, this mapping for the class field in question should be resolved and cached as part of the strategy on the first invocation of `map()` in `BoundMapperFacade`.

Comment: Can you explain this with an example? You meant to say I should call `factory.getMapperFacade(MtuInterfaceMap.class, MtuInterfaceMapUI.class, false)` before `factory.getMapperFacade(EdgeMtuMismatchEvent.class, EdgeMtuMismatchEventUI.class, false)` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`BoundMapperFacade` will lazily resolve the mapping strategy from the mapper factory and cache it on first invocation of the `map()` method. So all the required mapping definitions should be registered with the mapper factory at that time.

Depending on what is required, 3 solutions are available:

1. If the `MtuInterfaceMap` and `MtuInterfaceMapUI` classes have the same field set, there is no need to declare the `classMap` for them. Orika will copy the list elements by default, mapping the fields by name;
2. If the mapping is simple enough (e.g. copy values between fields with different names), `classMap` can be declared. The mapping for the parent class will use  it automatically when resolving the mapping strategy;
3. If custom mapping is required, one can write a custom converter and register it with the `MapperFactory`. In this case, the `classMap` definition for the parent class needs a hint to use this converter, with the `fieldMap().converter()` syntax. The custom converter can be written by extending e.g. `BidirectionalConverter<List<MtuInterfaceMap>, List<MtuInterfaceMapUI>>`.

The example code can be written as follows:

```
final DefaultMapperFactory factory = new DefaultMapperFactory.Builder().build();

// (1) auto-mapping
// nothing here

// (2) if the scenario is simple enough
factory.classMap(MtuInterfaceMap.class, MtuInterfaceMapUI.class)
       .field("comment", "details")
       .byDefault()
       .register();

// (3) if converter is required
final String listConverterId = "listConverter";
factory.getConverterMap()
       .registerConverter(listConverterId , new MtuInterfaceMapListConverter());


// 
factory.classMap(EdgeMtuMismatchEvent.class, EdgeMtuMismatchEventUI.class)
       .fieldMap("list", "list").converter(listConverterId).add() //  for case (3) only - declare converter
       .byDefault()
       .register();

BoundMapperFacade<EdgeMtuMismatchEvent, EdgeMtuMismatchEventUI> facade =
    factory.getMapperFacade(EdgeMtuMismatchEvent.class, 
                            EdgeMtuMismatchEventUI.class, 
                            false);
```